# Exporting Google Drive/Docs files to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-drive-api, google-cloud-dlp

We need to scan files with google dlp. However google dlp scanning is only supported in gcs. (https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/take-charge-of-your-data-scan-for-sensitive-data-in-just-a-few-clicks)
So I need to export the files with known file ID, to GCS and apply the google dlp scanning there.
Is there anybody here know that how to export files from google drive to GCS without manual intervention?

Answer (score 2):

This might do the trick

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Xc8E8mKC4MBvQ6Sw6akd_X5Z1cmHSNca

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

project_id = 'your-project-id'
!gcloud config set project {project_id}
!gsutil ls


bucket_name = 'medium_demo_bucket_190710'

!gsutil -m cp -r /content/drive/My\ Drive/Data/* gs://{bucket_name}/
```

Comment: It is very helpful. Appreciate that. What about auth? I didn't see that a login or credential file is required for auth.